# How to set admob on scrollView in swift4

Tags: ios, admob, swift4

When i set admob in ios, it's not appear advertisement

This is my code

```
class MainVC: UIViewController,UIScrollViewDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate , UITextFieldDelegate{
let myBanner : DFPBannerView = DFPBannerView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let request = GADRequest()
    request.testDevices = [kGADSimulatorID]

    //myBanner.delegate = self
    myBanner.rootViewController = self
    myBanner.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-7025295311419616/6321740358"
    myBanner.load(request)

}

func admob() {
 myBanner.frame = CGRect(x: (CGFloat(index) * (scrollview.frame.width * 0.6 + (scrollView_main.frame.width * 0.10)) + (scrollView_main.frame.width * 0.05)), y: 0 , width: scrollview.bounds.width * 0.6, height: scrollview.bounds.height * 0.8)


                scrollview.addSubview(myBanner)

                myBanner.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

                myBanner.frame.origin.x = (CGFloat(num) * (myBanner.frame.size.width + (scrollView_main.frame.width * 0.10)) + (scrollView_main.frame.width * 0.05))
                myBanner.frame.origin.y = 0
}
}
```

when i build appear this error

> UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
>   The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView
>   listed in  may also be helpful. 2018-05-05
>   19:45:15.004280+0900 Food[11788:202741] WF: === Starting WebFilter
>   logging for process Food2018-05-05 19:45:15.005328+0900
>   SUFOO[11788:202741] WF: _userSettingsForUser : (null) 2018-05-05
>   19:45:15.006396+0900 Food[11788:202741] WF: _WebFilterIsActive
>   returning: NO 2018-05-05 19:45:18.161588+0900 Food[11788:202741] WF:
>   _userSettingsForUser : (null) 2018-05-05 19:45:18.162901+0900 Food[11788:202741] WF: _WebFilterIsActive returning: NO

I need your answer thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if you're having a constraint issue.  I suggest to do this in storyboards where it is much easier.  If you insist on doing this in code, I recommend following this guide as it is written.  It is very explanatory.

[Guide](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/banner)